# What is the difference between silicon wafers in electronics and silicon wafers in solar cells?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, crystals, solar-cells

What is the difference between silicon wafers in electronics and silicon wafers in solar cells? are the the same? and if different why are they different?

Comment: A solar cell is essentially a special type of electronic diode. I'd guess that any type of silicon used for a solar cell has been used to make some sort of other electrical device. For various types of silicon used for solar cells see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell#Materials

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The specs on solar silicon are much looser. The main engineering/product concern is to make solar silicon as inexpensively as possible while still getting OK efficiency, at least for most terrestrial applications. Space and some niche applications on Earth tend to optimize for performance over cost, leading to more exotic layered solutions. (And I don't think EE would be a good place to get this answered).

Answer (score 1):

Silicon wafers in electronics are 51–450 mm diameter and 275-925 µm in thickness. However, wafers with diameters of 450 mm are not yet in general use.

Silicon wafers in solar cells are 100–200 mm in diameter and 200-300 μm in thickness. Anti-reflection coatings are applied to increase the amount of light coupled into the solar cell.

Comment: what about crystallinty? does monocrystalline or polycrystalline structure affect application?

Comment: Crystallinity affects the electronic properties, functionality, and reliability of silicon, as well as its potential applications. For example, monocrystalline silicon is well suited for VLSI devices such as microprocessors which cannot afford the structural imperfections associated with polycrystalline and amorphous silicon. On the other hand, polycrystalline silicon is more commercially feasible for large-area applications in conventional photovoltaic devices and as gate materials in MOSFET and CMOS technologies.